# How can I connect my Contact Form into Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, data-binding, ado.net

I am trying to connect my contact form using c# to a database so that all the input will be stored in a database, but I'm having a really hard time doing it. I don't have a code for my database yet because I just get so many errors.

Here is the code of my contact form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace CONTACT_US
{
    public partial class Contact_Form : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.IO.StreamWriter objWriter;
            objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Contact_us.txt",true);

            objWriter.Write("Name: " + TextBox1.Text + ", " + TextBox8.Text + " " + TextBox9.Text + Environment.NewLine);
            TextBox1.Text = string.Empty`enter code here`;
            TextBox8.Text = string.Empty;
            TextBox9.Text = string.Empty;

            objWriter.Write("Email Address: " + TextBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine);
            TextBox2.Text = string.Empty;

            objWriter.Write("Company: " + TextBox3.Text + Environment.NewLine);
            TextBox3.Text = string.Empty;

            objWriter.Write("Contact Number: " + TextBox11.Text + Environment.NewLine);
            TextBox11.Text = string.Empty;

            objWriter.Write("Subject: " + DropDownList2.Text + Environment.NewLine);
            DropDownList2.Text = string.Empty;

            objWriter.Write("Message: " + TextBox6.Text + Environment.NewLine);
            TextBox6.Text = string.Empty;

            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Confirm", "alert('Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch shortly.')", true);     
            }
         }
     }
```

How can I connect this one to a database?

Comment: what are the **ERRORS** ?

Comment: get  [sqlserver_express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx) then make a database then use VS to connect and generate Dataset or entity model ..... if none of this makes sense then I will help with more details on what doesn't or all  :)

Comment: We will put your querstion on hold until it start to make sense. Because right now it doesn't: " I am trying to connect my contact form using c# to a database... but I'm having a really hard time doing it. I don't have a code for my database yet..." You trying but you have no code. This is unusual

Comment: I'm using VS now, but can you be more specific about the details? Sorry, but I'm not really good with programming.

Comment: create a database first, with all the tables needed.. then go to toolbox and use LINQ datasource, do forget to connect / configure ur web config.

Comment: Hendras got it. but you need to learn about how to create relationships if you want more than one table in your database. either way sounds like you need to do a lot more research to tackle this problem.

Comment: @RadioSpace he asked about how to connect with database right? if he manage to connect his application to database, he can easily drag and drop any table he want to use in ".dbml" file, all he need to do is create all tables needed, with foreirgn keys too, and just drag and drop in dbml file. all relationship will be generated automatically.

Comment: search for "create a database in VS[version here]" and look at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data(v=vs.110).aspx) for the .net tools available for connecting to database. you have not told any details about the database you are trying to connect to and frankly I would not use StreamWriter like that.

Comment: As a practice, we were asked first to create a contact form, all the input will be stored in a text file. That's why I used StreamWriter like that.

And now he's asking for us to store the data/input in a database.

Comment: tag your question asp.net, ADO.net and databinding this question has little todo with SQL and SQLserver. Maybe database fits, but you will get better response with those tags. I would like to help you but I would need to write a complete, from ground up. Tutorial on Databases, databinding to asp.net controls, and ADO. That I think would be beyond the scope of a simple question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically create a Database in SQL Server or SQL Server Express(which is free) and add a Table called **Contact**. Add the following Columns to the table.[I assume you have the basic knowledge of sql table creation, etc.]
**ID** - which is the Primary Key, an integer value with auto-increment
**Name** - nvarchar
**Email_Address** - nvarchar
**Company** - nvarchar
**Contact_Number** - nvarchar
**Subject** -nvarchar
**Message** - nvarchar

Then in your **Contact_Form** class, make use of similar code/this code.

```
public void InsertMethod(){

    SqlConnection sqlConn = null;
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = null;

    try
    {
        String sqlConnectionString = "your database connection string";
        //create an sql connection, providing sql connection string
        sqlConn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
        //open the connection
        sqlConn.Open();  
        //insert statement with column names and parameters(@Name, @Email etc, the way how we can pass arguments for insert statement)
        String sqlCommandString =   "INSERT INTO Contact (Name, Email_Address, Company, Contact_Number, Subject, Message) " +
                                    "VALUES(@Name, @Email_Address, @Company, @Contact_Number, @Subject, @Message);";
        // Create the command object using sql connection string & sql connection
        sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommandString, sqlConn);
        //add values to the provided parameters
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBox1.Text);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email_Address", TextBox2.Text);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", TextBox3.Text);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact_Number", TextBox4.Text);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subject", TextBox5.Text);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Message", TextBox6.Text);
        //execute the SQL command(rowsAdded will give the number of rows added to the database)
        int rowsAdded = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw (ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        //closing the sql conncetion
        sqlConn.Close();
        //disposing
        sqlCmd.Dispose();
        sqlConn.Dispose();
    }}`
```

The above way is the very basic way of inserting data with the use of ADO.Net. Apart from this you can use techniques like LinqToSql, EF etc. Hope this will help.

Comment: may I supplement with [Connectionstrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx)